# Integral as countably additive map

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space. Then is $\mu : \mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$\mu(A)=\int_{A}X\,\mathrm{d}P$$
a countably additive set function, i.e. for $A_j\subseteq \mathcal{A}, j\in \mathbb{N}$ with $A_j$'s pairwise disjoint, is it true that? $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j\in \mathbb{N}}A_j\right)=\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_j)$$

I intuitively believe this is true, but since I don't know measure theory, I don't have any idea how to do this. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is true for finite sums by additivity of the integral, and for infinite sums by an application of the monotone convergence theorem (the finite sums of characteristic functions form an increasing sequence that converges to the infinite sum pointwise).

Comment: the way of doing this as described by Prahlad is also known as "the standard procedure" or "measure theoretic induction"

Comment: There's a whole theory on that issue that goes under the name "Daniell Integral".

Comment: Sorry, can you please tell me about the finite sums? I don't understand how is this happening, we want $\int_{A} X\mathrm{d}P + \int_{B} X \mathrm{d}P= \int_{A\cup B}X \mathrm{d}P$. I am sorry if this is standard procedure, but can someone tell me a little more on how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: @shadow10 By _definition_ $\int_EX\,dP=\int \mathbb 1_Ef\,dP$. That should make the finite additivity clear. For countable sums you really need measure theory. At some point you're going to need to learn some measure theory if you want to understand probability...